# Can i update a table structure and access it in a plpgsql function?

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a function in PostgreSQL to get data from a table in a dynamic way, but if i update the structure of "my_table_2023", it will raise the error because the structure doesn't match:

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type character varying(255) does not match expected type double precision in column 6.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT * FROM csv_congregational_ministries_2023_20240109090450;"
PL/pgSQL function dynamic_query_single_table(anyelement,integer) line 15 at RETURN QUERY
```

These are the functions and views used:

```
CREATE VIEW tables_per_year AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (basename, yyyy) yyyy, id, name, basename
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        created_at,
        name,
        CAST(SPLIT_PART(name, '_', -2) AS INTEGER) AS yyyy,
        LEFT(name, POSITION('_' || CAST(SPLIT_PART(name, '_', -2) AS TEXT) IN name) - 1) AS basename
    FROM "metabase_table"
    WHERE name LIKE 'csv_%'
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
) AS tables_per_year;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_table(_table_name text, year int)
RETURNS text AS $$
    DECLARE
        table_selected text;
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE 'SELECT name FROM tables_per_year WHERE name ILIKE $1 AND  yyyy = $2 LIMIT 1;'
        INTO table_selected
        USING '%' || _table_name || '%', year;

        RETURN table_selected::TEXT;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_query_single_table(_table anyelement, _year int)
RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS $$
    DECLARE
        table_partial_name text;
        table_selected text;
    BEGIN
        table_partial_name := pg_typeof(_table)::text;
        table_selected := get_table(table_partial_name, _year);
        EXECUTE FORMAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s; CREATE TABLE %s AS SELECT * FROM %s;', table_partial_name, table_partial_name, table_selected);

        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT * FROM %s;', table_selected);
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM dynamic_query_single_table(NULL::my_table, 2023);
```

I've tried to run the **DROP** and **CREATE** in a query and call **dynamic_query_single_table** in two different queries and it works fine.

I think it doesn't commit the queries with **DROP TABLE** and **CREATE TABLE** in **dynamic_query_single_table** because it's a single transaction.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is the DROP/CREATE sequence. Pretty sure it has to do with a conflict between `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT * FROM %s;', table_selected);` and `RETURNS SETOF anyelement`.

Comment: You don't want `anyelement` but `RETURNS SETOF record`.

Comment: @Bergi i tried to set `RETURNS SETOF record` but it raises an error because it requires a column definition list.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver so could it be a types conflict?

Comment: @TannicArturo98 If it's returning different columns for every call, you need to use `record`, and specify the column definition list in the query where you use the function

Comment: @Bergi how can i do it if it's dynamic and the columns could change?

Comment: @TannicArturo98 You can't, you (or the application that is issuing the query) must know the columns that they query produces (or at least the subset of columns that you are interested in).

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? What goal are you trying to achieve with these dynamic queries? Why do you have so many tables, and why do they all have different structures (columns)? E.g. if you add a column to `my_table_2023`, why don't you add the same column to `my_table_2024` (and `my_table_2022` and so on)? Why do you even have to store the names of tables in another table?

Comment: @Bergi I need to create a function to get the data of a table by passing the name and year from a filter in Metabase. Each table is created from a CSV uploaded to Metabase. There are different tables because they are annual data. The table names are retrieved from a View because I take the most recent ones from that year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using a TRIGGER and creating a function to create tables, this is the full code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_tables(year int)
RETURNS void AS $$
    DECLARE
        table_name_1 text := 'congregational_ministries';
        table_name_2 text := 'individual_ministries';
        table_selected_1 text;
        table_selected_2 text;
    BEGIN
        table_selected_1 := get_table(table_name_1, year);
        table_selected_2 := get_table(table_name_2, year);
        
        IF table_selected_1 IS NOT NULL THEN
            EXECUTE FORMAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s; CREATE TABLE %s AS SELECT * FROM %s;', table_name_1, table_name_1, table_selected_1);
        END IF;
        
        IF table_selected_2 IS NOT NULL THEN
            EXECUTE FORMAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s; CREATE TABLE %s AS SELECT * FROM %s;', table_name_2, table_name_2, table_selected_2);
        END IF;
        
        RAISE NOTICE 'Tables created.';
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_tables_trigger_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    DECLARE
        _year integer;
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT yyyy FROM tables_per_year WHERE name LIKE ''%s'' LIMIT 1;', NEW.name) INTO _year;
        
        PERFORM create_tables(_year);

        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_tables_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON metabase_table
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (
    NEW.name LIKE 'csv_congregational_ministries_%' OR NEW.name LIKE 'csv_individual_ministries_%'
)
EXECUTE FUNCTION create_tables_trigger_function();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_query_single_table(_table anyelement, _year int)
RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS $$
    DECLARE
        table_partial_name text;
        table_selected text;
    BEGIN
        table_partial_name := pg_typeof(_table)::text;
        table_selected := get_table(table_partial_name, _year);
        
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT * FROM %s;', table_selected);
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to handle the issue that you are currently experiencing  i would suggest you can use a combination of OUT parameters and EXECUTE statement to dynamically return the result.The following query below will create a function that has an OUT parameter called `result_table` that will hold the result set.

The `EXECUTE` statement is used to dynamically fetch the result set from the dynamically created table. The query is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_query_single_table(_table anyelement, _year int, OUT result_table anyelement)
AS $$
DECLARE
    table_partial_name text;
    table_selected text;
BEGIN
    table_partial_name := pg_typeof(_table)::text;
    table_selected := get_table(table_partial_name, _year);
    
   
    EXECUTE FORMAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s; CREATE TABLE %s AS SELECT * FROM %s;', table_partial_name, table_partial_name, table_selected);

   
    EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT * FROM %s', table_selected) INTO result_table;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

After creating the following query you can declare the above function as follows:

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE 
    result_set my_table;
BEGIN 
    PERFORM dynamic_query_single_table(NULL::my_table, 2023, OUT result_set);
END $$;
```

The above function will help you handle the dynamic structure of the table and return the result set without having issues with the structure mismatch.

Comment: I've edited "dynamic_query_single_table" function but when i execute the DO function it raises this error:
`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "result_set"`
`LINE 5: ..._table(NULL::my_table, 2023, OUT result_set...`